# passport authentication not working in nodejs using JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt, mean-stack, passport.js

I wanna implement passport authorization with jwt, but after running i've got token but the get function is not working. when i remove passport.authenticate it works fine. Even the console.logs are not working if the passport.authenticate is added to get function.

my passport.js file code

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('./../server/models/user');


module.exports = function(passport){
console.log('passport');
let opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken('jwt')
opts.secretOrKey = "secretkey";
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
    console.log(jwt_payload);
    User.getUserById(jwt_payload._doc._id, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if(user){
            return done(null, user);
        }else{
            return done(null, false);

        }
    });
}));
}
```

api.js (get function)

```
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), 
function(req, res){
console.log("prof");
res.json({user: req.user});
});
```

user.js(models)

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');



const userSchema = new Schema({
username: { type:String, lowercase:true, required:true, unique:true},
password: { type:String, required:true},
email: { type:String, lowercase:true, required:true, unique:true},

});

 userSchema.pre('save', function(next){
 var user = this;
 bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
    if(err) return next(err);
    user.password = hash;
    next();
 });
})




const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
   User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
const query = {username: username};
User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback)


 {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        } 
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you copy token from postman, make sure that you have the space after 'JWT' in the beginning of the token.  Also copy this to '/authenticate' api

```
         res.json({
                    success: true,
                    token: 'JWT '+token,
                    user: {
                        id: resUser._id,
                        name: resUser.username,
                        email: resUser.email
                    }
                })
```